# Is it possible to get a list of updated ECS containers in a Lambda function invoked from Code Pipeline?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline

I am deploying an application to ECS using Code Pipeline and I'd like to run a command on all new containers after they have been deployed.

There is the 'invoke' step which lets you run a Lambda function as part of the pipeline. This could be used to ssh into the containers and run the command, however I can't find how to get a list of the containers in the lambda function. Ideally it would be passed as an argument from the deploy step.

The only possible solution I've come across is to ssh into the EC2 instance on which the tasks are running, query the containers and then log into them and run the commands. This seems pretty involved for something I'm sure other people have done so I was hoping there was some API or something that I haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use boto3 library which can do the required stuff to collect the meta- data about the ECS instances.

2. code sample attached for `lambda_handler`. you can use the following methods of `ec2` `describe_instances` and `describe_instance_status`
3. [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances)

import boto3

from ec2 import describe_instances
from ecs import describe_container_instances

```
 global ECS_CLIENT
 if not ECS_CLIENT:
    ECS_CLIENT = boto3.client('ecs')


def get_instances():

  response = ECS_CLIENT.describe_container_instances('cluster_name')
  containerInstances = response.get('containerInstances')
  instances = []

  for reservation in containerInstances:
     reservation_status = reservation.get('status')
     instances += reservation_status 

  return instances
```

Apologies for miss that `ECS` bit. There is a method describe_container_instances in the same docs that i have shared for ECS. [ECS](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_container_instances)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am asking about ECS not EC2

Comment: @mmarklar Apologies for miss that `ECS`. 
There is a method `describe_container_instances` in the same docs that i have shared for ECS. 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.describe_container_instances